# Querying Stat tables using Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud, objectify

I am trying to perform a low-level Datastore query on one of the Stat tables (**Stat_Ns_Kind**) using Objectify.

The operation I'm trying to run looks like this:

```
ofy()
.load()
.kind("__Stat_Ns_Kind__")
.filter("kind_name", entityName)
```

I've tried it using a `.projection("count")` to only get the specific column, but Datastore complained about a missing index...
I've also tried omitting the projection and working with the full object from the result (`.single().now()`), but I always got a `null` result.

Can anyone suggest a proper way of doing this?

P.S. the operation executes within an Ofy context and all entities are registered properly. I've tried to execute the plain GQL on gcloud and I got the desired result, just need to translate that to OFY.

Comment: Objectify doesn't do anything special. If the GQL query works, the equivalent Objectify kind query will too. Post the *exact* GQL query you're using, the *exact* Objectify query you're using, and make 100% certain both are connected to the same datastore.

Comment: My GQL looks like this `select count from __Stat_Ns_Kind__ where kind_name = '{entityName}'`.
The objectify query looks as follows:
```Object result = ofy()
.load()
.kind("__Stat_Ns_Kind__")
.filter("kind_name", entityName)
.single()
.now()
```
The ofy result is null however and yes, both are connected to the same database. The only difference is that the GQL is executed directly in the datastore dashboard editor.

Comment: Hmmmm. Objectify just passes this request on to Google's low level Java client; there's no real magic in a request like this so there isn't any special syntax. If you're not getting data, this is almost certainly an issue between Google's library and the datastore. Some things I would try: 1) query that kind without a filter, see if you get any results, and 2) try fetching this data directly with the low level api. I'll try to dig up some sample code for you.

Comment: Run this and see if it works: https://gist.github.com/stickfigure/5bdc270980df7a5404b775cd07077a26

If it doesn't, remove the filter. If that still doesn't give you results, I'm afraid this is a question for Google. I don't know what goes on underneath that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it does work; you'll get an `com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity` as response where you can get the count with `getLong("count")`

Just make sure you are in the right namespace, as you are looking for the namespace specific stats. You can try to query `__Stat_Kind__` to see if it's a namespace issue

Comment: that was the issue indeed! I was working outside of the namespace I was expecting the data from.
Thanks!